# neo4j 3.0 embedded - no nodes

Tags: scala, neo4j, neo4j-embedded

There's sometime I must be missing about neo4j 3.0 embedded. After creating a node, setting some properties, and marking the transaction as success. I then re-open the DB, but there are no nodes in it! What am I missing here? The neo4j documentation is pretty poor.

```
      val graph1 = {
        val graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
          .newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("/opt/neo4j/deviceGraphTest" ))
        val tx = graphDb.beginTx()
        val node = graphDb.createNode()
        node.setProperty("name", "kitchen island")
        node.setProperty("bulbType", "incandescent")
        tx.success()
        graphDb.shutdown()
      }

      val graph2 = {
        val graphDb2 = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
          .newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("/opt/neo4j/deviceGraphTest" ))
        val tx2 = graphDb2.beginTx()
        val allNodes = graphDb2.getAllNodes.iterator().toList
        allNodes.foreach(node => {
          printNode(node)
        })
      }
```

Comment: I think you have to call `tx.close()` or `tx.finish()` after `tx.success()` to close the transaction. Can you try that?

Comment: Correct! Thanks K.E.! How about submitting an answer?

Comment: Perfect - Did you use `tx.close()` or `tx.finish()`? Tell me, then I will write an answer.

Comment: Yep, tx.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction what you have opened has to be closed with the command `tx.close()` after setting the transaction to state success. I do not know the exact scala syntax but it would be good to put the full block into a try/catch and to finally close the transaction in the finally block. 
Here is the documentation for Java: https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html